# eve framework and HMAC auth

Tags: rest, python-3.x, eve

I'm computing the HMAC of the HTTP body request in this way:

```
payload = {"name":"myvm","os":"gentoo","resources":{"vCPU":"4","RAM":"512","Disk":"1000"},"actions":["start"]}

key = "supersecretkey"
secret = bytes(key, encoding='utf-8')

msg = json.dumps(payload, sort_keys=True)
message = bytes(msg, encoding='utf-8')

print(hmac.new(secret, message, sha1).hexdigest())
```

After that I encode with b64 the hexdigest and send it with curl like the docs says `Authorization: paolo:$hmac_base64_encoded`

The problem is that I always get a 500 error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the exact curl request that you are using?

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: paolo:YjMyMzE4MmY1ZDIxZWQ4NDljNTE0ZWE3NDhiMDNlNTBlYTQzNGQyYQ==" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"myvm","os":"gentoo","resources":{"vCPU":"4","RAM":"512","Disk":"1000"},"actions":["start"]}' -i http://localhost:5000/vms`

Comment: I tried your request on 0.5-dev with a vanilla Auth class and it returns 422 (validation error basically) which is fine since I don't have your resource schema at hand. If you can edit the post above and add the code for your Auth class and maybe the schema of the resource, that would help a lot in triaging the issue

Comment: @NicolaIarocci I'm using Python 3.3.5 and I'm getting an interesting error in debug mode which says _hmac expect bytes and not str_. Can this be the problem?

PS: I'm using Eve-0.5 from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3x make sure that in your custom HMACAuth you are converting to bytes (the code snippet from the official documentation is for Python 2x).